# Google auth provider to login to my SF dev org

Tags: oauth2, authentication, google-apps

I am trying to learn OAuth flow and managed to complete an OAuth flow where Salesforce is the Auth provider as well as the Resource provider following [this article from Jeff Douglas](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Using_OAuth_to_Authorize_External_Applications)

Now I want to understand another scenario of the flow where Auth. Provider is Google. I was following step by step instructions from [this SF help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_provider_google.htm). I have created the Google Auth Provider from Setup > Auth. Providers, added the Consumer Key and Secret from my Google App, and updated the Google App with the callback URL generated by Salesforce for this Auth. Provider.

Then I log out of all active SF sessions and Google sessions of my browser, and hit the Test only initialization URL (something like https://login.salesforce.com/services/auth/test/00D1I000001fgDlUAI/MyOAuthProv)
. I am redirected to Google sign-in page as expected. I log in successfully. I am also being redirected to Salesforce. But now instead of being provided with an authorization screen, all I have is an XML:

```
<user>
<full_name>My Google Name</full_name>
<provider>Google</provider>
<org_id>my org id</org_id>
....
<portal_id>000000000000000</portal_id>
<locale>en-GB</locale>
<email>mygmail@gmail.com</email>
</user>
```

I never get any Authorization screen and I cannot access any SF page.

The header at the top says "Forwarding" and URL is:

https://mydevorg.my.salesforce.com/services/authcallback//?state=something&authuser=0&session_state=something&prompt=none#

Has any one got to get this flow working? I would be greatly obliged to know what I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the intended behavior of the "Test-only" URL - it shows you the user attributes returned by the Auth Provider, which helps with writing/debugging the Registration Handler.

For an actual Sign-In, you have to use the "Single Sign-On Initialization URL" (.../services/auth/**sso**/AuthProv). This should redirect you back to Salesforce with a signed-in user.